# Higher load time after adding Facebook SDK

Tags: jquery, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on adding Facebook social buttons for my website. You can view the [website here.](http://www.fantasylab.no)

I'm a beginner when it comes to Facebook API, however after adding the code in the footer, the load time of the website went much higher.

I did some research via Google, but I didn't find any good solution. I have tried to add open source jQuery social plugins, but that didn't go as I wanted.

I want to be able to use the default Facebook like/share buttons (which is currently on the footer).

Is there any way I can reduce the load time with the current code I have added with jQuery for example? Or is there any other way around so I can keep the default Facebook like/share buttons without affecting the load time?

Here is the current JavaScript code I have added after the `<body>` tag:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code at the footer:

```
<li><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div></li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add it at the end of the body tag and it should load.  Otherwise you can put the second part of that code in a onload block like `$(window).load(function(){ //FACEBOOK STUFF HERE });`  At the top of the body tags it inserts the script node and makes the page wait for facebook's sdk to load

Comment: I added it at the end of the body tag now, but still it has a high load time. Regarding the onload block, do you mean like this:


    `$(window).load(function(){
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    });`

Comment: Yup.  Try that.  It probably gets stuck waiting for that to load.  This way it would take longer for facebook to show, but the page should load.

Comment: Updated, the javascript code is at the end of the body tag with a onload block like you mentioned, but currently, the buttons arent showing at all with this code, do you know what I am maybe doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe facebook is also waiting on the onload which would have already passed.  inside the js section before the line with `js.src`... do the following: `js.onload = function(){ fbAsyncInit(); };`

Comment: Worked like a charm now! Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok then since we solved it, we moved the facebook loading to happen after the page loads like so:

```
$(window).load( function(){ 
    (function(d, s, id){ 
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} 
         js = d.createElement(s); 
         js.id = id; 
         js.onload = function() { fbAsyncInit(); }
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"; 
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 
});
```

The only change I made was to add an onload directly to the script tag which triggers on the load of the script since that loads after the body load, which triggers facebook's api to start up basically like normal.

Answer (score 2):

You may further improve the already accepted answer by changing the `sdk` url to:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?xfbml=false"
```

As noted here; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/advanced-setup/, this will reduce the payload size from `~200kb` down to `~60kb`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I guess this is the cleanest solution:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('body').prepend('<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=false&version=v15.0&appId={appID}"><\/script>');
});
</script>
```

Or if it's not important to display Facebook elements right after page loading, you can load it after the first scrolling event:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(window).one('scroll', function() {
    $('body').prepend('<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=false&version=v15.0&appId={appId}"><\/script>');
  });
});
</script>
```

This increased my GTMetrix performance result from 75% to 95% :)